# Make a mysqldump, gzip it and send to S3

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, gzip

as the title says, I am currently running into a problem which is that I can't directly gzip a dump and send it directly to my S3 bucket.

Here's my code which sends the dump directly unzipped. (It's working)

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u user2021 -p12345678 --single-transaction ticketing | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/subfolder/bkup_ticketing.sql
```

How could I, before sending it directly to S3 to **gzip it**.

Comment: `mysqldump .... | gzip | aws ....`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command I use currently to backup to any S3 compatible storage:

```
mysqldump mydatabase --ignore-table-data=mydatabase.some_table | gzip | aws s3 cp - --endpoint=https://nyc1.digitaloceanspaces.com s3://bucketname/mybackups/`date +\%Y/\%m/\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S`.sql.gz
```

All you need to do before executing this command is run the setup for the AWS CLI once:

```bash
aws configure
```

**on the linux account you are going to run this command on**. This will ask for a bucket key and secret which you can find/generate in your S3 service of choice.

Explanation:

- Create a sql dump for the database `mydatabase` and exclude the table data for `some_table` (you can add more `--ignore-table-data=...` arguments if needed).
- Gzip the output (this does not keep any local file on your server, it is all directly piped to aws).
- Send it to a DigitalOcean S3 server (any S3 compatible service should work) by setting a custom `--endpoint` for the `aws` command.
- Save it in a nice subdirectory as a timestamped file. The end directory of the backup file will look something like: `/bucketname/mybackups/2022/11/2022-11-04_11:17:48.sql.gz` (so all backups are nested in monthly directories).

Now simply put the command above in a CRON and enjoy your database backups.